# convert this java code to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

i use all ways to transfer array from php to js but the best solution is to use

```
JSON_encode($arr);
```

and all way to decode it fail
finally i decide to do it manually where the data received in JavaScript are like this: ["208","2812"] which converted to integer array by this java code but i don't know how to transfer it to javascript

```
String arr = "[\"208\",\"2507\"]";

//this its the output of him ["208","2507"]

String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

int[] results = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Are you parsing a JSON with php, but you want to transfer it to javascript? I'm.... really confused.

Comment: SO is not a porting service. Learn Javascript.

Comment: Also, this looks like an instance of the X-Y problem. "and all way to decode it fail" – decoding JSON in JavaScript should be trivial. Why not ask for help with doing that?

Comment: @user1874258 the JS in JSON stands for Javascript...  No need to do all kinds of unsavory things to make JS read JSON.  You should also promply forget you ever saw that piece of Java, it's ugly.  Use GSON or Jackson if you need to parse or generate JSON in Java.

Comment: I have no idea why you tagged this with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string in JSON format like you have:

```
var arr = "[\"208\",\"2507\"]";
```

You can get an actual array with:

```
var items = JSON.parse(arr);
```

Though that contains strings. To turn the strings into integers:

```
var results = items.map(function(v){return parseInt(v,10);});
```

Or in one line:

```
var results = JSON.parse(arr).map(function(v){return parseInt(v,10);});
```

But if you need the items in the array to be integers, why don't you just output integers in the first place, rather than strings:

```
var arr = "[208,2507]";
```

Then all you need is:

```
var results = JSON.parse(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should've used a JSON in Java, too.

In JavaScript, it should look like this:

```
var arrstring = "[\"208\",\"2507\"]";
var items = JSON.parse(arrstring);
var results = [];
for (var i=0, i<items.length; i++)
    results[i] = parseInt(items[i], 10);
```